# How to create a mapping type in civicrm?

Tags: php, import, mapping, civicrm

I need to create a new mapping type like Import Contribution / Import Contact.
How can I create that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we have to create one option group named mapping_type. Inside that option group we can create mapping types like Import Contact or Import Contributions